# Oracle ROWID for Sqoop Split-By Column

Tags: sqoop

I have a huge oracle table (Transaction), the data in my oracle table has skew data on the column "Customer id" due to which the few mappers take time in hours to finish the job while other mappers finish the job in minutes. I couldn't see any other option to avoid the skewing data as this is the only column can be splited by. We can combine other columns like Customer ID, Batch ID, SEQ NUM to come with multi column split but I understood that sqoop doesn't support multi column in split by.

My objective is to pull the transaction data for a specific period (i.e. batch date unique for a month of data).

I tried the below options in sqoop with 10 mappers.

```
--split-by "my column name"           //for example customer id
--where "my query condition"         //for example batch date
```

Now I am thinking of using the ROWID which might split the rows evenly between the mappers. I thought of using the boundary query to get the MIN & MAX ROW ID. Below is Sqoop command I want to use.

```
sqoop import \
--table Transaction \
--split-by ROWID \
--where "BATCH_DT=TO_DATE('03/31/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')" \
--boundary-query "SELECT MIN(ROWID) AS MIN, MAX(ROWID) AS MAXL FROM Transaction WHERE BATCH_DT=TO_DATE('03/31/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') GROUP BY CUSTOMERID, BATCHNO,BATCHSEQNO " \
--num-mappers 10 \
--target-dir /user/trans
```

Need advise if this would be right option or is there any other way.

Also I would like to know if we can use multi split-by column name by any chance.

Answer (score 2):

Providing `--boundary-query` will only save your time in *evaluating minimun and maximun value*. All mappers will have the same range query.

In your case, sqoop will generate boundary query like -

`SELECT MIN(ROWID), MAX(ROWID) FROM (Select * From Transaction WHERE BATCH_DT=TO_DATE('03/31/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') ) t1`

You can try this query and your custom boundary query on your JDBC client to check which one is faster and use that one.

> Now coming to uneven mappers load.

Yes, you are right. Currently, sqoop doesn't support multi-column in split by. you have to choose one column. If `ROWID` is evenly distributed (*I am assuming yes*), you should use it.

So, you query looks good. Just check compare`--boundary-query`.

---

### Edit

There is no proper java type issue with `ROWID` type of Oracle.

Add `--map-column-java ROWID=String` in your import command to map this to Java's String.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the boundary query as suggested. Now I am getting 2 issues. One is the warning message "Split may not partition". The other one is a error which terminated the sqoop job. The error is  "Sqoop does not have the splitter for the given SQL data type. Please use either different split column (argument --split-by) or lower the number of mappers to 1. Unknown SQL data type: -8"

Comment: @Yoga Firstly, You don't need to write `--boundary-query  "SELECT MIN(ROWID), MAX(ROWID) FROM (Select * From Transaction WHERE BATCH_DT=TO_DATE('03/31/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') ) t1"` manually. This is what sqoop will generate internally when you did not use `--boundary-query`.  Add `--verbose ` in the end of your sqoop command to see extended logs. You will find this command in these logs. I did not say this query is faster than your  custom boundary-query. I just want you to compare these and use the better one...:)

Comment: @devツ When I tried this, it looks like Sqoop is complaining that ROWID has to be one of the columns in the table?

Comment: @jkamei Sorry for late reply. Can you please share exact problem? You can ask a new question.

Comment: @devツ no problem at all. We ended up going a different route and splitting on a different column. The problem we were seeing was that "--map-column-java" seemed to specifically want columns in the Oracle table so it rejected ROWID. We also tried using oraoop but this killed performance. I'll go ahead and create a new question once we have to solve this problem :) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have index on SEQ NUM, if so then you can use SEQ-NUM in --split-by (i am assuming that SEQ-NUM no generating randomly it is populating in incremental fashion for each transaction ). so your sqoop command may look like this

```
sqoop import \ 
--table Transaction \
--split-by SEQ-NUM \
--where "BATCH_DT=TO_DATE('03/31/2016','MM/DD/YYYY')" \ 
--num-mappers 10 \
--target-dir /user/trans
```

Comment: No, the table has index on batch date and customer id. The SEQ_NUM is not a incremental field. For a batch date we may have multiple customer and for each customer id, the seq_num will be incremental. So SEQ_NUM will have duplicate value for a batch date. The combination of Batch date, customer id and seq_num will be unique.