# Sqoop trying to --split-by ROWID (Oracle) fails

Tags: oracle11g, sqoop

(be Kind, this is my first question and I did extensive Research here and on the net beforehand. Question [Oracle ROWID for Sqoop Split-By Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327682/oracle-rowid-for-sqoop-split-by-column) did not really solve this issue, as the original Person asking resorted to using another column)

I am using sqoop to copy data from an Oracle 11 DB.
Unfortunately, some tables have no index, no Primary key, only partitions (date). These tables are very large, hundreds of millions if not billions of rows.
so far, I have decided to Access data in the source by explicitly adressing the partitions. That works well and Speeds up the process nicely.

I need to do the  splits by data that resides in each and every table in order to avoid too many if- branches in my bash script. (we're talking some 200+ tables here)

I notice that a split by 8 Tasks results in very uneven spread of workload among the Tasks. I considered using Oracle ROWID to define the split.

To do this, I must define a boundary-query. In a Standard query `'select * from xyz'` the rowid is not part of the result set. therefore, it is not an option to let Sqoop define the boundary-query from --query.

Now, when I run this, I am getting the error

```
   ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job:

 java.io.IOException: Sqoop does not have the splitter for the given SQL

 data type. Please use either different split column (argument --split-by) 

or lower the number of mappers to 1. Unknown SQL data type: -8
```

samples of  ROWID :

AAJXFWAKPAAOqqKAAA

AAJXFWAKPAAOqqKAA+

AAJXFWAKPAAOqqKAA/

it is static and unique once it is created for any row.

I cast this funny datatype into something else in my boundary-query

```
sqoop import -Dorg.apache.sqoop.splitter.allow_text_splitter=true --connect

 jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:port:mydb  --username $USER --P --m 8

 --split-by ROWID --boundary-query "select cast(min(ROWID) as varchar(18)), cast

( max(ROWID)as varchar(18)) from table  where laufbzdt > 

TO_DATE('2019-02-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD')" --query "select * from table

where laufbzdt > TO_DATE('2019-02-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and \$CONDITIONS " 

--null-string '\\N' 

--null-non-string '\\N'
```

But then I get ugly ROWIDs that are rejected by Oracle:

```
select * from table where laufbzdt > TO_DATE('2019-02-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 

and ( ROWID >= 'AAJX6oAG聕聁AE聉N:' ) AND ( ROWID < 'AAJX6oAH⁖⁁AD䁔䀷' ) ,

 Error Msg = ORA-01410: invalid ROWID
```

how can I resolve this properly?

I am a LINUX-Embryo and have painfully chewed myself through the Topics of bash-shell-scripting and Sqooping so far, but I would like to make better use of evenly spread mapper-task workload - it would cut sqoop-time in half, I guess, saving some 5 to 8 hours.

TIA!
wahlium

Answer (score 0):

You can try **ROWNUM**, but I think `sqoop import` does not work with `pseudocolumn`.

Comment: ROWNUM is only valid for one single select. When Sqoop is using split-by, this will not be a unique ID across all splits, I assume. ROWID is static and unique as long as that row exists within the table.